# Check if an object exists with a property set to a particular value in a nested object (array of objects)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to construct a JSON object from a data source  which should look something like this:

```
var allProduce = [
        {"name": "cabbage", "type": "vegetable"},
        {"name": "potoato", "type": "vegetable"},
        {"name": "carrot", "type": "vegetable"},
        {"name": "apple", "type": "fruit"},
        {"name": "orange", "type": "fruit"}
]
```

As I work through the data source, I want to add to the nested object **'allProduce'** a new object with the corresponding entry *if and only if the object doesn't already exist.*

So if I have in my data source the following rows:

```
**Product          Type     Country origin      In stock?**
apple            fruit       Ireland             Yes
apple            fruit       France              Yes
apple            fruit       USA                 No
cabbage          vegetable   UK                  Yes
cabbage          vegetable   France              No
```

then the resultant 'allProduce' nested object should be:

```
var allProduce = [
        {"name": "apple", "type": "fruit"},
        {"name": "cabbage", "type": "vegetable"}
 ]
```

This is where I'm confused as I'm not sure how I check each time (without looping through the whole nested object?), whether or not the record exists. I'm doing something like this (using jQuery:

```
 $('.sourceData table tbody tr').each(function(i,row) {
    var fruitName = $.trim($(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').text()); 
    var type = $.trim($(row).find('td:nth-child(2)').text()); 

    if (AN OBJECT WITH THE "NAME" PROPERTY SET TO fruitName DOESN'T ALREADY EXIST) {
       allProduce.push({"name":fruitName, "type": type});

    }
 });
```

What should be in the brackets of the if statement, where I currently have *(AN OBJECT WITH THE "NAME" PROPERTY SET TO fruitName DOESN'T ALREADY EXIST)*. Or is there maybe a better approach to this?

Comment: You have to loop through the whole object, or else maintain an index (a separate object with the key values as property names, so you can do a quick `in` test).

Comment: OK, thanks. The separate index sounds best to me in this case — probably more efficient and easier to follow in the code.

Comment: Can you not use the name value as the property name instead, like `allProduce = { apple: { type: "fruit" } };` or even simpler `allProduce = { apple: "fruit" };`, then you don't care if it's already there - just set it.

Comment: Just to clarify : `allProduce[fruitName] = type;`

Comment: @Archer — yes thank you — that would work better probably but in this case I have to provide the JSON object in a particular format. Another problem is that the property names aren't 'clean' (they have things like brackets and spaces in them) so I imagine that would cause problems if they were used as properties.

Comment: Is allProduce meant to be an array, because you have it as an object in the script above which is invalid (unnamed objects inside it)

Comment: @Archer, you're correct. I wrote the code as an example but it actually looks something like this:       treeData = {"name" : "A", "children" : [
{"name" : "A1" },
{"name" : "A2" },
{"name" : "A3", "children": [
{"name" : "A31", "children" :[
{"name" : "A311" },
{"name" : "A312" }
]}] }
      ]};  I'll edit my question shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery's `filter()` method:

```
$('.sourceData table tbody tr').each(function(i,row) {
    var fruitName = $.trim($(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').text()); 
    var type = $.trim($(row).find('td:nth-child(2)').text());

    if ($(allProduce).filter(function(index, object){return object.name == fruitName;}).length == 0) {
       allProduce.push({"name":fruitName, "type": type});

    }
 });
```

Comment: Brilliant — that works perfectly and dispenses with the need for an extra object or array to keep track. Requires jQuery but I'm using it so no problem. Thank you very much. If nothing unforeseen crops up will accept your answer shortly.

Comment: Only drawback I have with the solution is it doesn't search within an object (e.g. I have an object which itself doesn't have the property but within that object there is another object which does have the property).

Comment: Note that the part doing all the work is the function passed to the `.filter()` method. This function will be called by JQuery for each element of the set you're filtering. For each element, if the function doesn't return `true` then this particular element will be filtered out. So you can do whatever you want inside this function and design your own filtering function. For instance, you could firstly check if your object has the property you're looking for, if so then check it has the correct value, and if not, then check sub-objects, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object as a HashSet to see if a certain name has been encountered. An example below:

```
(function () {
    var exists = {};
    $('.sourceData table tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
        var fruitName = $.trim($(row).find('td:nth-child(1)').text());
        var type = $.trim($(row).find('td:nth-child(2)').text());

        //AN OBJECT WITH THE "NAME" PROPERTY SET TO fruitName DOESN'T ALREADY EXIST
        if (!exists[fruitName]) {
            exists[fruitName] = true;
            allProduce.push({"name": fruitName, "type": type});

        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. If I understood correctly, this is similar to using a separate Array (as suggested by @Pointy in the comments above) just to keep track of whether the object has already been added to allProduce. If that's correct is there a particular advantage to using an object instead of say an array and using jqeury.inArray or .indexOf to check for the existence?

Comment: @pingin The advantage would mainly be that you won't be searching through a list for every iteration of `.each`. That would be `O(n*m)` where `n` is the # of elements and `m` is # of elements in `allProduce`. Since objects are backed by HashTables in JS then this way you only do a lookup on the object which is `O(1)`.